# How to use font-weight and font-family in styled components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, tsx

When I am trying to use font-weight and font-family when creating a styled component, nothing happens. Is there some specific way to set font-weight and font-family, when using styled components?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

```
export const H3 = styled.h3`
  font-size: ${fontsize.H3FONTSIZE};
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "museo", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have works perfectly fine.

## Complete example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const fontsize = {
  H3FONTSIZE: '400px',
}

export const H3 = styled.h3`
  font-size: ${fontsize.H3FONTSIZE};
  font-weight: 10000;
  font-family: "museo", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
`;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<H3>Hello</H3>)
  }
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/styled-components-rbd4xo?file=index.js

[image]